# Why are the manually added notification icons don't hide when using workspace switcher?

Tags: 11.04, workspaces, notification-area

For Example; notice `emesene` and `desktopnova` before and after clicking  <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Why not report it? See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @Flimm: At first I thought it was a bug. but there is a fix, see the answer below.

Comment: @binarylife: Still seems like a bug to me. Why would anyone need just the old-style system tray icons and not the new indicator icons?

Comment: @Flimm: Oh You mean the idea of the new indicators ?This is bother me two. but I just add them manually, cause I need them a lot. I hope they will improve this in 11.10.

Comment: @binarylife: I mean, in the workspace switcher, only the old-style system tray icons are displayed. Either the entire bar of both old-style system tray icons and new indicator icons should be displayed, or not. No half and half.

Comment: @Flimm: I agree with you.The developers meant to show nothing ,but these old-style tray icons are displayed because they aren't a part of the unity design.So Yeah I think we should report this as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in `CCSM`; Compiz config settings Manager.

Go to  Expo - Appearance - Check hide panels/dock:

[image]

Here is a new screenshot without the manually added notification icons : 
[image]